# Automatically set page order on create page

Tags: pages, order, post-editor, automation

Is there a way to **automatically set page order** to the last order number **upon creating new pages** instead of having it set to 0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use ajax and the `admin_footer-post-new.php` hook. The sql would vary depending on whether you want the highest or most recently published order number. The following returns the highest published order number + 1:

```
function wpse155926_set_menu_order() {
    $ret = array();

    if ( check_ajax_referer( 'wpse155926_set_menu_order_post', 'nonce', false /*die*/ ) ) {
        global $wpdb;
        //last published
        //$sql = $wpdb->prepare( 'SELECT menu_order FROM ' . $wpdb->posts . ' WHERE post_type = %s AND post_status = %s ORDER BY post_date DESC LIMIT 1', 'page', 'publish' );
        //highest published
        $sql = $wpdb->prepare( 'SELECT menu_order FROM ' . $wpdb->posts . ' WHERE post_type = %s AND post_status = %s ORDER BY menu_order DESC LIMIT 1', 'page', 'publish' );
        if ( ( $result = $wpdb->get_var( $sql ) ) !== false ) {
            $ret['menu_order'] = $result + 1;
        }
    }

    header('Content-type: application/json');
    die( json_encode( $ret ) );
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_wpse155926_set_menu_order', 'wpse155926_set_menu_order' );

function wpse155926_admin_footer_post_new_php() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    (function ($) {
        $.post( ajaxurl, {
                action: 'wpse155926_set_menu_order',
                nonce: <?php echo json_encode( wp_create_nonce( 'wpse155926_set_menu_order_post' ) ); ?>
            }, function(response) {
                if (response && response.menu_order) {
                    $('#pageparentdiv input[name="menu_order"]').val(response.menu_order);
                }
            }, 'json'
        );
    })(jQuery);
});
</script>
<?php
}
add_action( 'admin_footer-post-new.php', 'wpse155926_admin_footer_post_new_php' );
```

Comment: This works really well. One addition, though, I think the `$result` should be **offset by one** so it would be a new **unique** number and in the last page order. Eg. `$ret['menu_order'] = ++$result;`

Comment: Ah yes but you asked for last order number - not last + 1!

Comment: Oh, and by the way, I think you should use the commented **query** instead, which uses `ORDER BY menu_order`, since I am looking for the **highest value** (with the addition of the `post_status`, of course). That query should be the correct one.

Comment: Ok, updated answer per your comments.

Answer (score 2):

You could hook into the `publish_page` transitional status action and use a simple SQL query (via `$wpdb`) to determine the highest current value of `menu_order` in the `{prefix}_posts` table and set the `menu_order` of the new page accordingly. Example code:

```
add_action( 'publish_page', 'wpse155926_set_to_last_page', 10, 2 );
function wpse155926_set_to_last_page( $ID, $post ) {
  if ( $post->menu_order === 0 ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $query = "SELECT MAX(menu_order) FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type LIKE 'page' AND post_status LIKE 'publish';";
    $max_menu_order = $wpdb->get_var( $query );
    $post->menu_order = ++$max_menu_order;
    remove_action('publish_page', 'wpse155926_set_to_last_page');
    wp_update_post( $post );
    add_action('publish_page', 'wpse155926_set_to_last_page');
  }
}
```

Comment: I think `menu_order` is shared between the different **types of posts**, including _nav menu items_ even. @bonger's [_query_](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/155979/1044) seems to be better targeted. Also, with your code, _publishing_ the page seems to take ages and then leads to a **blank page**.

Comment: I think I found the solution to the **blank page** issue: [**infinite loop**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_post#Caution.21). In your case, anyway, the `publish_page` action should be **removed** and then **re-added**. With this fix, along with @bonger's _**query**_, the overall code is working in the right direction... Still testing, though.

Comment: Okay, your code **with the above fixes** seems to work. However, the process **runs on every update** of the page, thus moving any updated page to the last order. So I added a condition within the function to **set the page order ONLY if it is not already set**: `if ( $post->menu_order === 0 ) {}`

Comment: Mind if update your answer with the fixes?

Comment: Answer updated.