# How to add next height number in Order Attributes inside the Add new page.

Tags: functions, theme-development, wp-admin, wpdb, admin-menu

[image]

By default, when a new page is added it will be given the next highest number not already assigned to a page.

Comment: This is not as simple as it sounds, what happens when you switch the parent page? In general the menu order is not used much in practice AFAIK since the UI is not very intuitive. When you need to order pages it is usually easier to use a menu.

Comment: See http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/155979/57034.

Comment: I have fix this issue. I have added same think like this... Thanx for support.

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action( 'admin_footer', 'my_action_javascript' ); // Write our JS below here
function my_action_javascript()
    global $wpdb;
    $pageposts = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT max(menu_order) FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND post_type ='post_trainers'");
    ?>

<script type="text/javascript" >
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

        var data = {
            'action': 'my_action',
            'whatever': <?=$pageposts?>
        };

        $.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
               if($('#menu_order').val()=='' || $('#menu_order').val()=='0')
                $('#menu_order').val(response);
        });
    });
</script> <?php
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action_callback' );
function my_action_callback() {
global $wpdb; // this is how you get access to the database

$whatever = intval( $_POST['whatever'] );

$whatever += 1;
echo $whatever;
wp_die(); // this is required to terminate immediately and return a proper response
}
```

I was fix this issue Yesterday